# How to get specific row items in sqlite table and android?

Tags: android, sqlite

I am totally new to sqlite and android. I have the following table that I input user information into:

```
private static final String CREATE_TABLE_USERS = "CREATE TABLE "
        + TABLE_USER + "(" + KEY_USER_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,"+ KEY_TAG + " TEXT,"
        + KEY_FIRSTNAME + " TEXT," + KEY_LASTNAME + " TEXT," + KEY_DOB + " TEXT," + KEY_GENDER + " TEXT,"
        + KEY_JOB + " TEXT );";
```

And another Table for incoming data containing (TAG,Date and Time):

```
private static final String CREATE_TABLE_LOG = "CREATE TABLE "
        + TABLE_LOG + "(" + KEY_LOG_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,"+ KEY_TAG + " TEXT,"
        + KEY_DATE + " TEXT," + KEY_TIME + " TEXT );";
```

All I want is to search the incoming "TAG" in TABLE_USER and get "FirstName" and "LastName" from TABLE_USER  and put those plus "Date" and "Time" into third table as follows:

```
private static final String CREATE_TABLE_MAIN= "CREATE TABLE "
        + TABLE_MAIN + "(" + KEY_MAIN_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,"+ KEY_TAG + " TEXT,"
        + KEY_FIRSTNAME + " TEXT," + KEY_LASTNAME + " TEXT,"+ KEY_DATE + " TEXT," + KEY_TIME + " TEXT );";
```

What is the best query to make that happen?

And This is the DatabaseHelper class Code:

```
public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
public static String DATABASE_NAME = "RFID_Database.db";
private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
private static final String TABLE_USER = "TABLE_USER";
private static final String TABLE_LOG = "TABLE_LOG";
private static final String TABLE_MAIN = "TABLE_MAIN";
private static final String KEY_USER_ID = "user_id";
private static final String KEY_LOG_ID = "log_id";
private static final String KEY_MAIN_ID = "main_id";
private static final String KEY_FIRSTNAME = "FirstName";
private static final String KEY_LASTNAME = "LastName";
private static final String KEY_TAG = "TAG";
private static final String KEY_DOB = "DOB";
private static final String KEY_GENDER = "SEX";
private static final String KEY_JOB = "JOB";
private static final String KEY_DATE = "DATE";
private static final String KEY_TIME = "TIME";
private Context mContext;
SQLiteDatabase database = this.getWritableDatabase();
private static final String CREATE_TABLE_USERS = "CREATE TABLE "
        + TABLE_USER + "(" + KEY_USER_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,"+ KEY_TAG + " TEXT,"
        + KEY_FIRSTNAME + " TEXT," + KEY_LASTNAME + " TEXT," + KEY_DOB + " TEXT," + KEY_GENDER + " TEXT,"
        + KEY_JOB + " TEXT );";

private static final String CREATE_TABLE_LOG = "CREATE TABLE "
        + TABLE_LOG + "(" + KEY_LOG_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,"+ KEY_TAG + " TEXT,"
        + KEY_DATE + " TEXT," + KEY_TIME + " TEXT );";

private static final String CREATE_TABLE_MAIN= "CREATE TABLE "
        + TABLE_MAIN + "(" + KEY_MAIN_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,"+ KEY_TAG + " TEXT,"
        + KEY_FIRSTNAME + " TEXT," + KEY_LASTNAME + " TEXT,"+ KEY_DATE + " TEXT," + KEY_TIME + " TEXT );";


public DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    mContext = context;
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    db.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE_USERS);
    db.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE_LOG);
    db.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE_MAIN);
}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS '" + TABLE_USER + "'");
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS '" + TABLE_LOG + "'");
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS '" + TABLE_MAIN + "'");
    onCreate(db);
}

public void addUser(String tag, String FirstName, String LastName, String Dob, String Sex, String Job ) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(KEY_FIRSTNAME, FirstName);
    values.put(KEY_LASTNAME, LastName);
    values.put(KEY_TAG, tag);
    values.put(KEY_DOB, Dob);
    values.put(KEY_GENDER, Sex);
    values.put(KEY_JOB, Job);
    db.insertWithOnConflict(TABLE_USER, null, values, SQLiteDatabase.CONFLICT_IGNORE);
}

public void addLog(String Tag, String Date_, String Time_) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(KEY_TAG, Tag);
    values.put(KEY_DATE, Date_);
    values.put(KEY_TIME, Time_);
    db.insertWithOnConflict(TABLE_LOG, null, values, SQLiteDatabase.CONFLICT_IGNORE);
}

public void addMain(String tag, String FirstName, String LastName, String Date, String Time) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(KEY_FIRSTNAME, FirstName);
    values.put(KEY_LASTNAME, LastName);
    values.put(KEY_TAG, tag);
    values.put(KEY_DATE, Date);
    values.put(KEY_TIME, Time);
    db.insertWithOnConflict(TABLE_MAIN, null, values, SQLiteDatabase.CONFLICT_IGNORE);
}


public ArrayList<UserModel> getAllUsers() {
    ArrayList<UserModel> userModelArrayList = new ArrayList<UserModel>();
    String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_USER;
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor c = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
    // looping through all rows and adding to list
    if (c.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            UserModel userModel = new UserModel();
            userModel.setId(c.getInt(c.getColumnIndex(KEY_USER_ID)));
            userModel.setTag(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(KEY_TAG)));
            userModel.setFirstName(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(KEY_FIRSTNAME)));
            userModel.setLastName(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(KEY_LASTNAME)));
            userModel.setDOB(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(KEY_DOB)));
            userModel.setSex(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(KEY_GENDER)));
            userModel.setJob(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(KEY_JOB)));
            userModelArrayList.add(userModel);
            } while (c.moveToNext());
     }
    return userModelArrayList;
}

public ArrayList<UserModel> Display_Logs() {
    ArrayList<UserModel> userModelArrayList = new ArrayList<UserModel>();
    String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_LOG;
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor c = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
    // looping through all rows and adding to list
    if (c.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            UserModel userModel = new UserModel();
            userModel.setId(c.getInt(c.getColumnIndex(KEY_LOG_ID)));
            userModel.setTag(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(KEY_TAG)));
            userModel.setDate_(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(KEY_DATE)));
            userModel.setTime_(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(KEY_TIME)));
            userModelArrayList.add(userModel);
        } while (c.moveToNext());
    }
    return userModelArrayList;
}


public ArrayList<UserModel> getMainLogs() {
    ArrayList<UserModel> userModelArrayList = new ArrayList<UserModel>();
    String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_MAIN;
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor c = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
    // looping through all rows and adding to list
    if (c.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            UserModel userModel = new UserModel();
            userModel.setId(c.getInt(c.getColumnIndex(KEY_MAIN_ID)));
            userModel.setTag(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(KEY_TAG)));
            userModel.setFirstName(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(KEY_FIRSTNAME)));
            userModel.setLastName(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(KEY_LASTNAME)));
            userModel.setDate_(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(KEY_DATE)));
            userModel.setTime_(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(KEY_TIME)));
            userModelArrayList.add(userModel);
        } while (c.moveToNext());
    }
    return userModelArrayList;
}

public void UpdateUser(int id, String User_ID, String FirstName, String LastName, String Dob,
                       String Sex, String Job ) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(KEY_TAG, User_ID);
    values.put(KEY_FIRSTNAME, FirstName);
    values.put(KEY_LASTNAME, LastName);
    values.put(KEY_DOB, Dob);
    values.put(KEY_GENDER, Sex);
    values.put(KEY_JOB, Job);
    db.update(TABLE_USER, values, KEY_USER_ID + " = ?", new String[]{String.valueOf(id)});
}

public void DeleteUser(int id) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    db.delete(TABLE_USER, KEY_USER_ID + " = ?",new String[]{String.valueOf(id)});
}


public void backup(String outFileName) {
    //database path
    final String inFileName = mContext.getDatabasePath(DATABASE_NAME).toString();
    try {
        File dbFile = new File(inFileName);
        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(dbFile);
        // Open the empty db as the output stream
        OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream(outFileName);
        // Transfer bytes from the input file to the output file
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        int length;
        while ((length = fis.read(buffer)) > 0) {
            output.write(buffer, 0, length);
        }
        // Close the streams
        output.flush();
        output.close();
        fis.close();
        Toast.makeText(mContext, "Backup Completed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Toast.makeText(mContext, "Unable to backup database. Retry", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public void importDB(String inFileName) {
    final String outFileName = mContext.getDatabasePath(DATABASE_NAME).toString();
    try {
        File dbFile = new File(inFileName);
        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(dbFile);
        // Open the empty db as the output stream
        OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream(outFileName);
        // Transfer bytes from the input file to the output file
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        int length;
        while ((length = fis.read(buffer)) > 0) {
            output.write(buffer, 0, length);
        }
        // Close the streams
        output.flush();
        output.close();
        fis.close();
        Toast.makeText(mContext, "Import Completed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Toast.makeText(mContext, "Unable to import database. Retry", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public void Delete_All(String Table_Name){
    SQLiteDatabase sql=this.getWritableDatabase();
    sql.execSQL("delete from "+ Table_Name);
}

public Cursor Search(String tag){
    SQLiteDatabase database = this.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = database.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM TABLE_USER WHERE TAG = '"+tag+"'", null);
    return cursor;
}

public String getUserName(String tag) {
    Cursor cursor = null;
    String firstName = "";
    String lastName = "";
    try {
        cursor = database.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_USER + " WHERE "+ KEY_TAG +"=?", new String[] {tag});
        if(cursor.getCount() > 0) {
            cursor.moveToFirst();
            firstName= cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(KEY_FIRSTNAME));
                lastName= cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(KEY_LASTNAME));
        }
        return firstName;
    }finally {
        cursor.close();
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Post the code that you have so far like your SQLiteOpenHelper class.

Comment: I added the DatabaseHelper class to the main question text. @forpas